# Convert a flexbox grid to stacked with different order

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I need to achieve the following responsive layout :

[image]

Here is the code I have for Desktop devices :

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    width: 264px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}

.sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1CA4FC;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #65D643;
}

.site-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #F7B92B;
  width: calc(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      Sidebar Header
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      Sidebar Footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site-content">
    Site Content
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I create a fluid layout for mobile devices where the flexbox ordering is as per the image above?

Comment: You can't without cloning/moving the site-content with JS. The three sections would need to be siblings, then you could change the order via `order`. 
You could better solve this with floats, though. Header and footer float left, content floats right. Still need to have the same parent, though.

Comment: For info, if `display:contents` comes implemented everywhere one day, these structure will be no longer trouble maker. (test in firefox : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/borJaY ) . There is also the grid model  that can be switched with the flex model . https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yzorEQ (sidebar-wrapper is then no longer needed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `div` structure, I would do it like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1ca4fc;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #65d643;
}

.site-content-mobile {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f7b92b;
}

.site-content {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 787px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .site-content-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-content {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100%);
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f7b92b;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      Sidebar Header
    </div>
    <div class="site-content-mobile">
      Site Content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      Sidebar Footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site-content">
    Site Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) You are awesome. This is exactly what I am looking for! Cheers!!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch between [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and avoid the extra `.sidebar-wrapper`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 264px;
  }
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 264px 1fr;
  }
}

.sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1ca4fc;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  order: 2;
  background-color: #65d643;
}

.site-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f7b92b;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  grid-row: auto / span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    Sidebar Header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-footer">
    Sidebar Footer
  </div>
  <div class="site-content">
    Site Content
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yzorEQ

---

Without modifying the structure , [`display:contents;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) would have been useful *(at this time, Firefox understands it - use FF to test result expected :( ).*

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  display: contents;
  width: 264px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 264px;
  }
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1ca4fc;
  order: 2;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #65d643;
}

.site-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f7b92b;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      Sidebar Header
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      Sidebar Footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site-content">
    Site Content
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/borJaY

---

**Note**: media queries are usually wrapping sets of selectors, not nested in the selector itself.

Comment: The first solution looks cleaner and widely supported by browsers I presume. But, `Site Header`, `Site Footer` divs are placed in reverse order.

Comment: @TaherJodhpurwala oh yes, order rule misplaced.  I would go too for the first and probably use header/footer and main tags. display-box contents seems handy, hope it will be widely supported one day .